How to use TM Forum's CTK to validate a Swagger file against Open API standards?
I'm working on an API that needs to conform to TM Forum's Open API standards. I have my API specification in a Swagger/OpenAPI file, and I want to use the Conformance Test Kit (CTK) to validate it. However, I'm not sure about the exact process.
My questions are:
Where can I download the official CTK for TM Forum Open API validation?
What are the steps to set up the CTK and run it against my Swagger file?
Are there any specific configurations I need to consider when testing against TM Forum standards?
How do I interpret the results? What kind of output should I expect?
If my API fails the conformance test, what are the typical next steps?
Additional Information:
I'm using OpenAPI 3.0 for my Swagger file
The API is related to [specific TM Forum Open API, e.g., TMF620 for Product Catalog Management]
My development environment: Windows
Any guidance or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I run the cmd file, installed dependencies and then nothing
